# React Native Flatlist onReachEnd (load more item) with bottom tabs navbar after scroll flatlist till bottom it's like re render flatlist component

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to make load more content on flatlist with bottom navbar 
but after I try to scroll til bottom of page 
the result is : new data show up but, idk why the flatlist like re render and move to top page again 
expected result : new data show up and screen not move to the top page again

note : if i try without bottom navbar (only flatlist) it works~

btw i'm using react native functional component 
dependency package 
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.7",
"react": "^17.0.2", 
"react-native": "0.65.1",

```
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState, useCallback} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  ScrollView,
  SafeAreaView,
  FlatList,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {Avatar, Card, Paragraph} from 'react-native-paper';
import {TouchableOpacity, RefreshControl} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import {
  IconShipTruck,
  IconShipTruckPending,
  IconShipTruckPendingActive,
  IconShipTruckGoing,
  IconShipTruckGoingActive,
  IconShipTruckHistory,
  IconShipTruckHistoryActive,
} from '../../assets';
import GLOBAL_STYLE from '../../assets/styles/global_style';
import {List} from 'react-native-paper';
import {_getStorageValue, STATUS_PENDING} from '../../utils/constant';
import axios from 'axios';
import Moment from 'moment';

const Shipments = ({navigation}) => {
  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  const [isFetching, setFetching] = useState(false);
  const [dataPending, setDataPending] = useState([]);
  const [dataOnGoing, setDataOnGoing] = useState();
  const [dataHistory, setDataHistory] = useState();

  // paging
  const [loadMore, setLoadMore] = useState(true);
  const [fetchLoad, setFetchLoad] = useState(false);
  const [pagePending, setPagePending] = useState(1);
  const [limitPending, setLimitPending] = useState(6);
  const [endReachMomentum, setEndReachMomentum] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    var page = 1;
    getPending('refresh', page); // refresh or initial data
  }, []);

  const handleLoadMore = useCallback(() => {
    if (loadMore == true) {
      // load more = true jika current page ada datanya
      setFetchLoad(true);
      var page = pagePending + 1;
      setPagePending(page);
      getPending('loadmore', page);
    }
  }, [pagePending]);

  const handleEndReach = ({distanceFromEnd}) => {
    if (!endReachMomentum) {
      handleLoadMore();
      setEndReachMomentum(true);
    }
  };

  const handleRefresh = useCallback(() => {
    var page = 1;
    setPagePending(page);
    setLoadMore(true);
    setFetching(true);
    getPending('refresh', page);
  }, []);

  async function getPending(type, page) {
    // initial data
    var data = [];

    var configsTemp = await _getStorageValue('@configs');
    if (configsTemp !== null) {
      var configs = JSON.parse(configsTemp);
      var baseUrl = configs.value;

      var authTemp = await _getStorageValue('@authorization');
      if (authTemp !== null) {
        var authorization = JSON.parse(authTemp);
        var accessToken = authorization.access_token;
        var tokenType = authorization.token_type;
        var username = authorization.user_data.username;
        var status = STATUS_PENDING;

        // req data pending
        var epPending = `${baseUrl}/shipment/get_ship_loads/${status}/${username}?p_current_pages=${page}&p_limit=${limitPending}`;
        var optionsPending = {
          headers: {
            accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: `${tokenType} ${accessToken}`,
          },
        };
        axios
          .get(epPending, optionsPending)
          .then(res => {
            if (res.data.status == 'SUCCESS') {
              data = res.data.data;
              if (type == 'refresh') {
                setDataPending(data);
                setLoadMore(true);
              } else if (type == 'loadmore') {
                if (data.length > 0 && data.length < limitPending) {
                  // kondisi data kurang dari limit
                  setPagePending(page);
                  setLoadMore(false);
                  setDataPending(prevData => [...prevData, ...data]);
                } else if (data.length == 0) {
                  // kondisi data kosong
                  setPagePending(page - 1);
                  setLoadMore(false);
                } else if (data.length == limitPending) {
                  // kondisi data terfulfill
                  setPagePending(page);
                  setDataPending(prevData => [...prevData, ...data]);
                }
              }
            }
            setFetchLoad(false);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            setFetchLoad(false);
          });
      }
    }
    setFetching(false);
  }

  const Item = ({data, moveTo}) => (
    <List.Section>
      <List.Accordion
        theme={{colors: {primary: 'black'}}}
        titleStyle={[styles.divLoadNumber]}
        title={
          <Text style={GLOBAL_STYLE.poppinsMedium}>
            {'[' +
              data.trans_type_desc +
              '] ' +
              data.site_initial_dc +
              ' - Load number ' +
              data.load_number}
          </Text>
        }
        titleNumberOfLines={1}
        descriptionStyle={styles.divLoadNumberDetail}
        descriptionNumberOfLines={5}
        description={
          <>
            <Paragraph style={GLOBAL_STYLE.poppinsRegular}>
              Total Container : {data.total_containers} {`\t\t`} Total Qty :{' '}
              {data.total_items_qty}
            </Paragraph>
            {'\n'}
            <Paragraph style={GLOBAL_STYLE.poppinsRegular}>
              Processing Date :{' '}
              {Moment(data.load_process_date).format('DD MMM YYYY HH:mm')}
            </Paragraph>
          </>
        }>
        {data.shipmentList.map((sl, index, navigate) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5'}}
              key={sl.id}
              disabled={index == 0 && sl.flag == 0 ? false : true}
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate(`${moveTo}`, {
                  loadNumber: data.load_number,
                  siteDc: data.site_code_dc,
                  dc: data.site_initial_dc,
                  dataHeader: sl,
                });
              }}>
              <List.Item
                style={{paddingBottom: 0, paddingTop: 0}}
                titleStyle={[
                  GLOBAL_STYLE.poppinsRegular,
                  styles.divPO,
                  {backgroundColor: '#e0e5e5'},
                ]}
                titleNumberOfLines={2}
                title={
                  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <View style={styles.divPODetailIndex}>
                      <Text style={GLOBAL_STYLE.poppinsMedium}>
                        {index + 1}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flex: 3}}>
                      <Text style={GLOBAL_STYLE.poppinsMedium}>
                        {'    '}
                        PO number : {sl.po_no}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                }
                descriptionStyle={styles.descriptionAccordionChild}
                descriptionNumberOfLines={4}
                description={
                  <>
                    <Paragraph style={GLOBAL_STYLE.poppinsRegular}>
                      Booking Number : {sl.transaction_no}
                    </Paragraph>
                    {'\n'}
                    <Paragraph style={GLOBAL_STYLE.poppinsRegular}>
                      Address :{' '}
                    </Paragraph>
                    {'\n'}
                    <Paragraph style={GLOBAL_STYLE.poppinsRegular}>
                      {sl.cust_address +
                        ', ' +
                        sl.cust_kecamatan +
                        ', ' +
                        sl.cust_kelurahan +
                        ', ' +
                        sl.cust_city}
                    </Paragraph>
                  </>
                }
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        })}
      </List.Accordion>
    </List.Section>
  );

  const renderItem = ({item}) => <Item data={item} moveTo={'OrderDetails'} />;

  const pendingFooter = useCallback(() => {
    if (loadMore == true && fetchLoad == true) {
      return (
        <View>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }, [loadMore, fetchLoad]);

  const shipmentList = useCallback(() => {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          {pagePending} : {loadMore == true ? 1 : 0}
        </Text>
        <FlatList
          data={dataPending}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          refreshing={isFetching}
          onRefresh={handleRefresh}
          onEndReached={handleEndReach}
          onEndReachedThreshold={0.000001}
          onMomentumScrollBegin={() => {
            setEndReachMomentum(false);
          }}
          ListFooterComponent={pendingFooter}
          ListFooterComponentStyle={{marginBottom: 20}}
          initialNumToRender={limitPending}
          maxToRenderPerBatch={limitPending}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  });

  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarStyle: {position: 'absolute', height: 60},
        tabBarLabelStyle: [GLOBAL_STYLE.poppinsRegular, styles.tabBarLabel],
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Awaiting to Delivery"
        component={shipmentList}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Pending',
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            const flag = focused;
            if (flag) {
              return <IconShipTruckPendingActive />;
            } else {
              return <IconShipTruckPending />;
            }
          },
          headerTitleStyle: [
            GLOBAL_STYLE.poppinsSemibold,
            GLOBAL_STYLE.headerTitleNavbar,
          ],
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

export default Shipments;

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  card: {
    height: 140,
    width: windowWidth * 0.96,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: 'black',
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    color: 'blue',
    shadowOffset: {
      height: 1,
      width: 0,
    },
  },
  cardTitle: {
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: 'blue',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
  },
  cardTitleOngoing: {
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: 'blue',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
  },
  tabBarLabel: {
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  divPODetailIndex: {
    flex: 3,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: 30,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  divLoadNumber: {
    backgroundColor: '#a5f5ef',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    marginTop: -13.5,
    fontSize: 14,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
  },
  divLoadNumberDetail: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderLeftWidth: 0.5,
    borderRightWidth: 0.5,
    borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
    marginBottom: -13.5,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
  divPO: {
    marginLeft: 30,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
  },
  descriptionAccordionChild: {
    marginLeft: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 10,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 10,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderLeftWidth: 0.5,
    borderRightWidth: 0.5,
    borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
  },
});
```

[No Bottom Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFqNq.gif)

[With Bottom Navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZltMT.gif)

Comment: The flatlist is getting re rendered because the data you pass it changes.

Comment: ty for your response @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ , i already add gif with description https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFqNq.gif (this flatlist work properly if no bottom navbar) but if i add bottom navbar the flatlist move to the top after i triggered onEndReached https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZltMT.gif

Answer (score 0):

OKEY GUYS I Found the answerrrr finally

1. create new file for flatlist only
2. on tabscreen component target to the new file

```
    <Tab.Screen
        name="Awaiting to Delivery"
        component={Pendings} => new file that flatlist only
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).